php pdo display/refer to previous row
I am trying to send an email with PHP mailer (works ok) but when i try to implement a feature to show the name of the previous user that received the email, it does not display the name. here is my code, hoping someone can point me in the right direction
i am pulling the previous user name using a query (query displays right result when run in sql) - i am not sure if there is a different way to do it
   <?php
/* php mailer code */

// db connection
require('connect.php');


//get count of records
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[distribution_list] WHERE [date_received] IS NULL");
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();


// run main query for body of email
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT TOP 1 [campaign], [rank], [email], [name], [date_sent], [date_received], DATEDIFF(HOUR, [date_sent], [date_received]) AS [difference] FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[distribution_list] WHERE [date_received] IS NULL order by [rank]");
$stmt2->execute();

// get previos user info
$stmt3 = $pdo->prepare("select * from [mydatabase].[dbo].[distribution_list] where [rank] = (select max([rank]) FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[distribution_list] where [date_sent] is not null and [date_received] is null ) - 1 ");
$stmt3->execute();


$previous_user = '';
while($result3 = $stmt3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $previous_user = $result3['name'];
}


$email = '';

//if there is an email, proceed to set it as the recipient, otherwise state no valid users
if ($count > 0) {

    while($result = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $mail->addAddress($result['email'], $result['name']);
                $name = $result['name'];
                $email = $result['email'];
                $campaign = $result['campaign'];

        if (str_contains($email , 'somedomain')) {
           $mail->Body="you have to validate ".$previous_user." entry, click here</a>";
       } elseif (!str_contains($email , 'somedomain')) {
           $mail->Body="Hello ".$name." you have to makea selection, click here";
       } else {
         // do nothing
       }
    }

} else {
    echo "no more valid users";
}




//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';



    
//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors and update db with date sent
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent! You can close the browser window';
    
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("WITH UpdateList AS (
                              SELECT TOP 1  * from [mydatabase].[dbo].[distribution_list] 
                              WHERE email=? and [date_received] IS NULL
                              ORDER BY rank asc 
                            )
                            update UpdateList 
                            set date_sent=getdate()");
    $stmt->execute([$email]);

}

?>

the quick solution that worked was within SQL
i created a view that looked like this
create view [dbo].[Distribution List] as (
select t1.*, t2.[name] as [previous user]
from
[mydatabase].[dbo].[distribution_list] t1
left join
(select [name], [rank]
from
[mydatabase].[dbo].[distribution_list]) t2 on
       t1.[rank] = t2.[rank] + 1
)

i then changed $stmt2 to select from this new view
this brought the previous user into the main sql table and in turn completely eliminated the need for $stmt3 and the associated while loop for it
thanks to all the suggestions

What do you expect us to do, if you aren't willing to show us the SQL?

@TimRoberts i've updated the query to show the sql

Please remember that one of the reasons you write in an abstract programming languages is to make it easier for humans to understand what your code is doing. This means choosing your variable names wisely. Numbering your variables seems silly in that context. It, for instance, requires you to explain them with comments. It also is a great help for creating hard to track bugs.

I have a feeling that you don't quite grasp what loops and variables in code do. You loop over results of $stmt3 in a way that doesn't make much sense. $previous_user will only contain the value of the last iteration. You also continuously assign a new value to $mail->Body in your second loop. Also, and this isn't really a bug, it isn't wise to include all email addresses in the To: field of the email with addAddress(), better use addBcc() so people can't see each others email addresses. Better still, send emails individually.

You could have $stmt3 = $pdo->prepare("select name from distribution_list...") and then use $stmt3->fetchColumn(); instead of using a loop, but that's a micro-optimization.  Are you GUARANTEED there will be a record where date_sent is not null and date_received is null and rank is maximum minus 1?

And, by the way, you don't need [brackets] around your field names unless the names have spaces.  And you don't need to say "mydatabase.dbo" each time.  That's a lot of unnecessary typing.
